# How to create sumif in datastudio without error for auto aggregated field?

Tags: looker-studio

The goal is to get house% which is House/Total Impressions, so I created two calculated fields:

First formula:

'''case when Line item type = 'House' then SUM(Total impressions) END'''

and so I can create second formula to get the solution which is:

first formula / total impressions.

But the problem is I think auto aggregated field (total impression) which is giving the issue, is there any way to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Line item type = 'House' THEN Total impressions END)
```

Data Studio parser is very buggy. When you face these weird errors, try alternative ways to write the same code until you find one that works.